# Do there exist provably true theorems whose proofs are too long for us to ever discover?

Tags: logic, proof-theory

I know Godel's theorems state that there exist mathematical statements which are true but not provable. I am concerned here with provably true mathematical statements whose "minimal" proof length makes a proof impractical in the real world.

Does there exist a theorem which can be described with $N$-bits, where $N$ is relatively small (e.g., small enough that said theorem written in this form can be reasonably read by a human), which is provable within some standard axiomatic framework (say ZFC), but whose minimal proof length $M$ is sufficiently large that a proof within our physical universe is impossible (say $M \gg 10^{100}$)?

Comment: See [Gödel's speed-up theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_speed-up_theorem)

Comment: I **strongly suspect** that the sentence "There is no $\mathsf{ZFC}$-proof of a contradiction involving fewer than Graham's-number-many symbols" cannot be proved in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ in many fewer than Graham's-number-many steps. Hoewver, the situation around this sort of question is surprisingly subtle; see e.g. the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417484/proving-short-consistency-can-we-do-better-than-brute-force-search). (Interestingly, there is a very short $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proof of the $\mathsf{ZFC}$-provability of that sentence! *HINT: casework re: consistency of ZFC ...*)